# Unable to read the data if the first tag has namespace while unmarshalling

Tags: java, namespaces, unmarshalling, castor

I have the following xml in which `<first>` tag has the namespaces in it .
I am not able to get the `<second>` tag data.

```
<first xmlns= "url" xmlns:xsi="url" xsi:schemaLocation="url">
    <second> hello world </second>
</first>
```

Mapping file i have written :

```
<mapping>
    <description>A mapping file</description>
    <class name="com.example.data.First">
           <field name="xmlns" type="string" >
               <bind-xml name="xmlns" node="attribute" />
           </field>
           <field name="xmlnsxsi" type="string" >
               <bind-xml name="xmlns:xsi" node="attribute" />
          </field>
          <field name="xsischemaLocation" type="string" >
              <bind-xml name="xsi:schemaLocation" node="attribute" />
          </field>
        <field name="second" type="String"/>
    </class>
</mapping>
```

What should i change in the mapping file to get the value of ?

I am getting

`org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException: The namespace associated with the prefix: 'xmlns' is null.`